# Trying to do a rake db migrate and I keep getting this errror

Tags: oracle, ruby-on-rails-4, oracle11g, rubygems

```
Migrating to AddDeviseToUsers (20140704194919)
```

== 20140704194919 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================

-- change_table(:users)
   (36.9ms)  ALTER TABLE "RA_USERS" ADD "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
 OCIError: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kkdlSetColDTypeDfltProps0], [], [], [], [], [], [], []: ALTER TABLE

"RA_USERS" ADD "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
rake aborted!

StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

OCIError: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kkdlSetColDTypeDfltProps0], [], [], [], [], [], [], []: ALTER TABLE "RA_USERS" ADD "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULLstmt.c:230:in oci8lib_210.so

THIS IS MY GEMFILE.lock

Xubuntu

remote: https://rubygems.org/

specs:

```
actionmailer (4.1.1)
  actionpack (= 4.1.1)
  actionview (= 4.1.1)
  mail (~> 2.5.4)
actionpack (4.1.1)
  actionview (= 4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  rack (~> 1.5.2)
  rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
actionview (4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  builder (~> 3.1)
  erubis (~> 2.7.0)
activemodel (4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  builder (~> 3.1)
activerecord (4.1.1)
  activemodel (= 4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  arel (~> 5.0.0)
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.5.5)
activesupport (4.1.1)
  i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
  json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
  minitest (~> 5.1)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
  tzinfo (~> 1.1)
angular-rails-templates (0.1.3)
  railties (>= 3.1)
  sprockets
  tilt
angular-ui-bootstrap-rails (0.11.0)
angularjs-rails (1.2.22)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
audited (4.0.0.rc1)
  rails-observers (~> 0.1.2)
audited-activerecord (4.0.0.rc1)
  activerecord (~> 4.0)
  audited (= 4.0.0.rc1)
bcrypt (3.1.7)
better_errors (2.0.0)
  coderay (>= 1.0.0)
  erubis (>= 2.6.6)
  rack (>= 0.9.0)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
  debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.1)
  sass (~> 3.2)
builder (3.2.2)
cancan (1.6.10)
coderay (1.1.0)
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
coffee-script (2.3.0)
 coffee-script-source
  execjs
coffee-script-source (1.7.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
devise (3.3.0)
  bcrypt (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
  railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
  warden (~> 1.2.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
docile (1.1.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.2.1)
factory_girl (4.4.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
  factory_girl (~> 4.4.0)
  railties (>= 3.0.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.11)
jbuilder (2.1.3)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
  multi_json (~> 1.2)
jquery-rails (3.1.1)
  railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
  thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
json (1.8.1)
libv8 (3.16.14.3)

 mail (2.5.4)
 mime-types (~> 1.16)
  treetop (~> 1.4.8)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (5.4.0)
multi_json (1.10.1)
ng-rails-csrf (0.1.0)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
phantomjs (1.9.7.1)
polyglot (0.3.5)
quiet_assets (1.0.3)
  railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rails (4.1.1)
  actionmailer (= 4.1.1)
  actionpack (= 4.1.1)
  actionview (= 4.1.1)
  activemodel (= 4.1.1)
  activerecord (= 4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.1.1)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
  rails-observers (0.1.2)
  activemodel (~> 4.0)
  rails_12factor (0.0.2)
  rails_serve_static_assets
  rails_stdout_logging
  rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
  rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
  railties (4.1.1)
  actionpack (= 4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
  rake (10.3.2)
redcarpet (2.2.2)
ref (1.0.5)
rspec-core (3.0.4)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-expectations (3.0.4)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-mocks (3.0.4)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-rails (3.0.2)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-support (3.0.4)
ruby-oci8 (2.1.7)
sass (3.2.19)
sass-rails (4.0.3)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
  sass (~> 3.2.0)
 sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
 simplecov (0.9.0)
  docile (~> 1.1.0)
  multi_json
  simplecov-html (~> 0.8.0)
 simplecov-html (0.8.0)
 sprockets (2.11.0)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  sprockets (~> 2.8)
teaspoon (0.8.0)
  railties (>= 3.2.5, < 5)
therubyracer (0.12.1)
  libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
  ref
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
  polyglot
  polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
uglifier (2.5.3)
execjs (>= 0.3.0)
  json (>= 1.8.0)
warden (1.2.3)
  rack (>= 1.0)
webrick (1.3.1)
yard (0.7.5)
yard-rails (0.3.0)
  yard

PLATFORMS
 ruby

 DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter
angular-rails-templates
angular-ui-bootstrap-rails
angularjs-rails
audited-activerecord (~> 4.0.0.rc1)
better_errors
binding_of_caller
bootstrap-sass
cancan
coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
devise
factory_girl_rails
jbuilder (~> 2.0)
jquery-rails
ng-rails-csrf
phantomjs
quiet_assets
rails (= 4.1.1)
rails_12factor
redcarpet (= 2.2.2)
rspec-rails
ruby-oci8
sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
simplecov
teaspoon
therubyracer
uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
webrick
yard (= 0.7.5)
yard-rails (= 0.3.0)
```

The data base is Oracle 
Never ran into this is issue could be a lock on my database I would need to resolve or something else?

Comment: That's bad.  That's an internal Oracle error.  You would need to contact Oracle support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out its not being able to add a not null column to a table already containing data. Oracle does this to keep integrity of the DB.